# PhoneGap Html simple HTML not working

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

I am trying to learn create an app with PhoneGap but I cannot seem to get the most basic HTML to work. I have stripped it down to the following in the index.html page:

```
<html><body>
<a href="http://somesite.com/page.php"> Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the resulting app it shows the page fine, but clicking the link does nothing.

Comment: Let me guess, you are trying to make existing website to android app?

Comment: Right now I am simply trying to learn by starting with the most basic html I could think of.

Comment: For opening websites you must use plugin called inAppBrowser

Comment: <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.7.1" />  

Is in my config.xml

Comment: If you want call some link outside your mobile app; you must use Javascript.. Check [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) link!